# How to test setter methods in gtest?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I've heard that using gtest we should test all public methods of testing class. But what about setter method which change value of private/protected? How should I test it? Example below.

```
class Formatter
{
public:
    Formatter();
    void setFormat(std::string format)
    {
         formatPattern = format;
    }
    std::string format(ExampleObject objectToFormat)
    {
         //do something with objectToFormat using protected formatPattern
         //and put output to std::string retval
         return retval;
    }

protected:
    std::string formatPattern;
};
```

EDIT: format() method added.

Comment: you call get, check the value, then you call set and another time get and compare those values. If the value has changed like you expected it works.

Comment: But what if (just like in my example) I don't have getter method?

Comment: you just write one? I mean what's the purpose of an internal private variable if you don't use it anyways? And if you do use it it would probably change some result so you could check if the expected changes happened.

Comment: Made edit to show what I try to say. Now I don't need any 'get' method (according to 'tell dont't ask' rule). Format() method is easy to test, but it should be tested after setFormat() method, because it uses setFormat() result. So how can I check setFormat() in this situation?

Comment: Well, if you test without using `setFormat` and one time after using `setFormat` you will have tested all possible cases and both methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found answer for my problem. Before test I create new class which is inherited from formatter. Then, in this class, I implement getter method necessary to test my public setter method in parental class.

```cpp
namespace consts {
    std::string simpleFormatPattern = "@name @severity @message";
    std::string formatterOutput  = "error ERROR Here is some message";
    LogEntry logEntry("error","Here is some message", ERROR);
} //namespace consts

class ut_formatter : public Formatter
{
public: 
    ut_formatter()
    {}
    ~ut_formatter()
    {}

    std::string getFormatPattern(void)
    {
        return formatPattern;
    }
};

TEST(ut_formatter, SetFormatOk) 
{
    ut_formatter formatter;
    formatter.setFormat(consts::simpleFormatPattern);

    ASSERT_EQ(consts::simpleFormatPattern, formatter.getFormatPattern());
}

TEST(ut_formatter, FormatOk) 
{
    ut_formatter formatter;
    formatter.setFormat(consts::simpleFormatPattern);

    ASSERT_EQ(consts::formatterOutput, formatter.format(consts::logEntry));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You test the effect that setting the private/protected variable would have. For example:

```
std::ostringstream a, b;
a << 32;
ASSERT_EQ(a.str(),"32");
b << std::hex() << 32;
ASSERT_EQ(b.str(),"20");
```

In this example, 'std::hex()' sets some internal formatting for the ostringstream, which you can see in the .str() output.

Comment: In your example you use getter method (str()) and in my example (also in my problem) I haven't one.

Comment: @user3148625 In your case, you would check the result of your invocation of `format`. (e.g., call `setFormat`, call `format`, and then make sure the result corresponds with the value specified earlier in `setFormat`.)

Answer (score 0):

There is much to be said for the view that you *shouldn't* unit-test
the internals of an API, just the public behaviour. If you decide to do it
anyway, the googletest way us to use the macro:

```
FRIEND_TEST(TestCaseName, TestName)
```

which is defined in the header `gtest/gtest_prod.h`.

Here's an example test runner that applies this to your class `Formatter`:

**Formatter.h**

```
#include "gtest/gtest_prod.h"
#include <string>

class Formatter
{
    FRIEND_TEST(t_Formatter_setFormat, t_formatPatternSetCorrect);
public:
    Formatter(){};
    void setFormat(std::string format)
    {
         formatPattern = format;
    }
    // Methods, methods...

protected:
    std::string formatPattern;
};
```

**test runner**

```
#include "Formatter.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include <string>

TEST(t_Formatter_setFormat, t_formatPatternSetCorrect) {
    Formatter f;
    f.setFormat("A%Format%Pattern");
    EXPECT_EQ(f.formatPattern,"A%Format%Pattern");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

As you would guess,

```
FRIEND_TEST(t_Formatter_setFormat, t_formatPatternSetCorrect);
```

just makes the test a friend of class `Formatter`, so it can access protected 
and private members.

You see here that the solution is intrusive in the sense that you need to
include `gtest_prod.h` in `Formatter.h`. But `gtest_prod.h` itself
carries no baggage - here's [the code](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/source/browse/trunk/include/gtest/gtest_prod.h?r=535) 
so you can include this header in the distribution of your software without 
incurring any dependencies. No need to bundle googletest as a whole into your distribution.

[Further reading](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Testing_Private_Code)